# See stack trace of python methods Odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo-8

In Odoo 8, I want to do several actions by Python code, pressing only one button:

- Create an invoice from a sale order
- Validate that invoice
- Register payment of that invoice

If I see the code for validating an invoice, when I press "Validate", I see that Odoo calls `invoice_validate()` method. But if I only call this method, it isn't generate internal number, and other things. Only following this steps work: [Odoo validate invoice from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35375213/odoo-validate-invoice-from-code) .

So, where can I see the complete list of methods Odoo call when I press a button? Thanks!

Comment: Its part of your investigation and your experiences towards the work in odoo flow becuase odoo doen't provide any kind of documentation for method calling and button click action .you have to learn from the code as well as its functionality from the scratch and then after you have to implement it in your development flow

Answer (score 0):

Methods can be called from various locations. And many methods rely on the fact that other methods have already run before them. Here's some guidelines that I've found useful when working on similar tasks.

Methods can be run by:

- Buttons when clicked
- Onchange methods defined in View XML (old api).
- Workflows

Usually the first methods that would run are the ones defined in the view. Go through them and study what they are doing and if you will have to call them as well. Sometimes they perform various important calculations/data population.

Once the button gets clicked, it can call a method, or simply transition the workflow, or the called method might transition the workflow, etc. So it is important that you check what the corresponding workflow does as well.

It usually helps to study what is the input and output of the methods involved, including what gets passed around in the context, to get a better picture what is the path to automating the various steps.

Each module can be different, depending on its developers' programming approach, the api features that were available at its time of implementation, etc. So it will take some effort to understand the sequence of events for your specific case. Still, once you go through this a couple of times it gets much more intuitive.

To answer your question - the complete list of methods is in the code. You can use various dev/debug tools (your browser's dev console for one) to help you on the way.